# Using AND gate as a comparator

Tags: gate-driving, class-d

I amb trying to desing a very simple Gate Driver for a Class-D audio amplifier.
In order to introduce the Dead Time my first thought was to use a RC conected to a comparator as an imput of an AND gate. Something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSynIn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But then I realised that, since I'll be working at a frequency arround 300 kHz I'll need a very fast Op Amp (something arround 50\$V/\mu s\$, right?)

So in order to reduce costs, can I ommit the Op Amp and connect the RC to the AND gate?

If so, how do I ajust the dead time? Through trial and error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, connect RC straight to the (N)AND gate, but use one Schmitt  trigger input NAND, e.g. CMOS 4093. Anyway most likely you don't need any RC or logic to introduce dead time you need. I beleive this can be easily and reliabily achieved just shunting power MOS gate resistor with a fast diode. Do it such as MOS turns on via resistor (with delay) but switches off via diode (faster)

Comment: how much dead time do you need?

Comment: Something arround 0.1us

Comment: What type of diode should I use? Maybe a Schoktty diode?

Comment: Yes a Schottky is okay, you may have to tweak a little RG value to spot a good tradeoff between switch-on losses and dead time. Otherwise since a gate driver is needed anyway you may use one of the (many) half bridge gate drivers with built-in dead time. Just search your favourite supplier.

Comment: Thanks @carloc, why do you say a gate driver is needed anyway?

Comment: High frequency MOS driving requires quite some current if you want to keep losses low,  I just guessed you were using gate drivers.

Comment: The problem is this is a part of a college project and we are not allowed to use a gate driver

Comment: More info would be needed, your circuit, mosfets, power and supply levels ....your knowledge about power electronics... may you just ask your lecturer

Comment: It has to be able to supply at least 1W of power to a 8 ohm resistor.

Comment: Its my first subject about power electronics, I will ask my lecturer but thanks anyway ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Op amps don't tend to make very good comparators. Comparators tend to be better at being comparators. A bog standard LM393 is quoted at TI as switching in 0.3 µs, is that fast enough?

*edited to correct my symbol foolishness on Janka's advice*

Comment: nitpicking: Should be us or µs, not uS or µS, as S (Siemens) is 1/Ω.

Comment: @Janka noted :)

Comment: Sins I'm trying to reduce costs as much as possible, I think I'll go with @carloc solution. But thanks anyway :)